# Include header in multiple .csv file with cat linux

Tags: scripting, csv

I need to include a .csv header in multiple .csv files at once by switching the name to:

> originalname1c.csv, originalname2c.csv, originalname3c.csv

Currently, the procedure is done as follows:

```
cat header.csv originalname1.csv > originalname1c.csv
cat header.csv originalname2.csv > originalname2c.csv
cat header.csv originalname3.csv > originalname3c.csv
```

Etc.

Is it possible to add header to multiple files as in the above example in a single command?

additional one: what if the filenames were random? keeping the rule from: anyname.csv to anynamec.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
for name in anyname*.csv; do
    cat header.csv "$name" >"${name%.csv}c.csv"
done
```

Here, `anyname*.csv` is some shell pattern, possibly including a directory path that matches the names of the CSV files to which you want to prepend the contents of `header.csv`.  Ideally, this pattern should not match the name `header.csv`.  If it is, consider moving it to some other place, renaming it, or inserting an explicit test to skip it:

```bash
for name in anyname*.csv; do
    [ "${name##*/}" = header.csv ] && continue
    cat header.csv "$name" >"${name%.csv}c.csv"
done
```

or, in the `bash` or `zsh` shell,

```bash
for name in anyname*.csv; do
    [ "$name" -ef header.csv ] && continue
    cat header.csv "$name" >"${name%.csv}c.csv"
done
```

(Or don't bother with it and delete the `headerc.csv` file that may be generated.)

The loop iterates over the matched names and creates the new files by concatenating the header with the CSV records, creating a file whose name will be the same as the original file's but with the `.csv` file name suffix replaced by `c.csv`.

The standard expansion `${var%pattern}` expands to `$var`, but with the shortest suffix string matching `pattern` removed.  The expansion `${var##pattern}` is also standard and removes the longest matching prefix string from `$var`.  One example above uses this to remove any directory path from `$name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 1 2 3; do cat header.csv originalname${i}.csv > originalname${i}c.csv; done
```

or

```
for i in name1 mynameH arglebargle; do cat header.csv ${i}.csv > ${i}c.csv; done
```

Further, for a bunch of numbered files:

```
for i in $(seq 1000); do cat header.csv file${i} > file${i}c.csv; done
```

`$(seq 1000)` could also be `{1..1000}`

This gets you

```
cat header.csv file1 > file1c.csv
cat header.csv file2 > file2c.csv
cat header.csv file3 > file3c.csv
.
.
.
cat header.csv file998 > file998c.csv
cat header.csv file999 > file999c.csv
cat header.csv file1000 > file1000c.csv
```

A general way to do this is with this line:

```
for i in *.csv; do if [ "$i" != header.csv ]; then cat header.csv "$i" > $(basename "$i" .csv)c.csv; fi; done
```

The command "basename" takes apart the path given, and hands back just the filename, and if you have specified the suffix, as we have here with .csv, removes that part as well. Then we add the "c", put the .csv back, and there's the new files name.

The "if" condition skips the header file, otherwise it'll get catted up as well.

Comment: `for ((i=1; i <= 1000; i++)); do ...; done` or `for i in {1..1000}` avoids the need for `seq`

Comment: Cool, I was wondering about that. The Bash manual was less than forthcoming in a quick scan...

Comment: Yes, the manual is incredibly dense: there are no wasted words in it.  The manual online is useful in that you have both a table of contents and an index. You'll want to look at [3.2.5.1 Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs)

Comment: It didn't work for me.

The number of files is random.

The file name is random.

In that case, how could I do it?

cat head.csv random.csv > samerandomnamec.csv